# Component in grid layout

Tags: html, css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to put component in grid layout with [this library](https://svelte-grid.vercel.app/), but image of this component is rendering incorrectly:

[image: current screenshot].

It should look like this:

[image: screenshot].

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import Grid from './lib/Grid/src/index.svelte'; 
  import Note from './lib/Note.svelte'; 
  import gridHelp from './lib/Grid/src/utils/helper';
  
  const breakpoint = 1200;
  const column = 6;
  const cols = [[breakpoint, column]];
  
  const id = () => "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  
  let items = [
  {
    6: gridHelp.item({
      x: 2,
      y: 0,
      w: 1.7,
      h: 3,
    }),
    id: id(),
  },

  {
    6: gridHelp.item({
      x: 2,
      y: 0,
      w: 2,
      h: 2,
    }),
    id: id(),
  },
]
</script>

<Grid {cols} bind:items={items} let:item={item} rowHeight={100}>
  {#each items as { x, y, w, h, component }}
    <div style="grid-column: {x + 1} / span {w}; grid-row: {y + 1} / span {h};">
      <Note />
    </div>
  {/each}
</Grid>
```

And code of component:

```html
<!-- lib/Note.svelte -->
<div class="note-container">
    <img src="/note-template.png" class="note-temp" alt="note">
    <span class="header">Header</span>
    <!--<hr class="header-divider">-->
</div>

<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
    .note-temp {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 404px;
        height: 406px;
    }
    .header {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        font-family: Poppins;
        top: 70px;
        left: 27px;
        color: #5A482C;
        font-family: Poppins;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    /*.header-divider {
        position: relative;
        width: 320px;
        height: 4px; 
        background: #5A482C;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left: 235px;
        margin-top: 73px;
    }*/
</style>
```

Im trying to ChatGPT's variant:

```html
<script>
  import Grid from './lib/Grid/src/index.svelte'; // Check if the path is correct
  import Note from './lib/Note.svelte'; // Check if the path is correct
  
  const breakpoint = 1200;
  const column = 6;
  const cols = [[breakpoint, column]];
  
  const id = () => "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  
  let items = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2, component: Note },
    { x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, component: Note },
  ];
</script>

<Grid {cols} bind:items={items} let:item={item} rowHeight={100}>
  {#each items as { x, y, w, h, component }}
    <div style="grid-column: {x + 1} / span {w}; grid-row: {y + 1} / span {h}">
      <svelte:component this={component} />
    </div>
  {/each}
</Grid>
```

But it's don't working. I'm expecting correct render. Thanks in advance! And sorry for my english btw.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's work now corerct! Good luck! –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you that you are using `Grid` the wrong way. It already internally iterates the `items` and provides each item as a [slot property](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#slot-slot-key-value) called `item`.

By having another `#each` inside the Grid, you are creating a nested loop.

It probably should look something like this:

```html
<Grid {cols} bind:items={items} let:item={item} rowHeight={100}>
  <!-- item is the current item from let:item -->
  {@const { x, y, w, h, component } = item} 
  <div style="grid-column: {x + 1} / span {w}; grid-row: {y + 1} / span {h};">
    ...
  </div>
</Grid>
```

You might want to explain in more detail what the code is supposed to do and how it relates to the images.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's work now corerct! Good luck!